# Tweepy: extended mode with api.search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've written a simple script to get the most trending 300 tweets containing a specific hashtag.

```
for self._tweet in tweepy.Cursor(self._api.search,q=self._screen_name,count=300, lang="en").items(300):
        self._csvWriter.writerow([self._tweet.created_at, self._tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

It works well and it save the result to CSV but **the tweets are truncated**.

I modified the code like this, adding the `twitter_mode=extended` parameter:

```
for self._tweet in tweepy.Cursor(self._api.search,q=self._screen_name,count=300, lang="en", tweet_mode="extended").items(300):
        self._csvWriter.writerow([self._tweet.created_at, self._tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

But I got this **exception**:

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'text
```

My question is: **how can I save an complete tweet using a Cursor?** (complete = not truncated)

Thanks in advance (and sorry, I'm a Tweepy newbie trying to learn as much as possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close, do this instead:

```
for self._tweet in tweepy.Cursor(self._api.search,q=self._screen_name,count=300, lang="en", tweet_mode="extended").items(300):
    self._csvWriter.writerow([self._tweet.created_at, self._tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Notice that I used `full_text` in `self._tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')`, rather than just `text`. The `text` property is null when you use `tweet_mode='extended'` and the tweet appears in `full_text` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! I was going crazy! :)